# Switch word postions in Notepad ++

Tags: text, replace, position, notepad++, cpu-word

My text looks like this:

```
Text1 | Text2 | Text3 | Text4 | Text5 | Text6 | Text7
```

And I want to change text positions like this

```
Text1 | Text4 | Text5 | Text6 | Text2| Text3 | Text7
```

And if it's possible to remove the `|` between Text 4, 5, 6, so that it looks like

```
Text1 | Text4 Text5 Text6 | Text2 | Text3 | Text7
```

If it is not possible, I'll be happy if the first problem is solved.

Comment: What is the rule? How do you define what is to be matched/moved?

Comment: Read the text I want to change the text 4 5 6 2 3 positions in between every test there is a |

Comment: Great, so what is blocking you?

Comment: I need to do it on every line theres like 100lines like this so I want a quick way to change it if theres any not to go manualy one by one as it will take me a long itme

Comment: You may use `^([^|]*\|)((?:[^|]*\|){2})((?:[^|]*\|){3})` to replace with `$1$3$2`

Comment: Thanks for help it worked problem solved

Answer (score 1):

You may use

```
^([^|]*\|)((?:[^|]*\|){2})((?:[^|]*\|){3})
```

And replace with `$1$3$2`.

**Details**:

- `^` - start of a line
- `([^|]*\|)`  - Group 1 (`$1`) capturing zero or more chars other than `|` and then a literal `|`
- `((?:[^|]*\|){2})` - Group 2 (`$2`) capturing 2 sequences of the same pattern as in Group 1
- `((?:[^|]*\|){3})` - Group 3 (`$3`) capturing 2 sequences of the same pattern as in Group 1

The order is changed with the order of the backreferences in the replacement pattern.

To remove the 2nd, 3rd and 4th `|`, use a similar expression:

*Find what*: `^([^|]*\|)([^|]*)\|([^|]*)\|([^|]*)`
*Replace with*: `$1$2$3$4`

Basically, you just manipulate the capturing group boudaries and the order of the backreferences in the replacement pattern, that is all.